# How to select percentage values per group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select percentage values for each group in mySql.

I tried to do it in memory, but it is a lot of code to maintain. It would be graceful if I do it via SQL.

I am selecting the following data:

```
Gender,Category,Month,Year,NumberOfCustomers
'female','Feature Phones','1','2019','1000'
'male','Feature Phones','1','2019','10000'
'female','Smart Phones','1','2019','30000'
'male','Smart Phones','1','2019','200000'
'female','Feature Phones','2','2019','20000'
'male','Feature Phones','2','2019','15000'
'female','Smart Phones','2','2019','30000'
'male','Smart Phones','2','2019','150000'
```

Using the query:

```
SELECT gender, category, month, year, 
SUM(number_of_customers) AS numberOfCustomers
FROM customer_table 
WHERE brand_id IN (100) 
AND category in (1,2)        
AND month in (1,2) and year in (2019)
GROUP BY month, year, category, gender;
```

What I want is percentage of customers in each month. Ex:

```
Gender,Category,Month,Year,NumberOfCustomers,PercentageCustomersPerMonth
'female','Feature Phones','1','2019',5000,2.04
'male','Feature Phones','1','2019',10000,4.08
'female','Smart Phones','1','2019',30000,12.24
'male','Smart Phones','1','2019',200000,81.63
'female','Feature Phones','2','2019',20000,9.30
'male','Feature Phones','2','2019',15000,6.97
'female','Smart Phones','2','2019',30000,13.95
'male','Smart Phones','2','2019',150000,69.76
```

Is there a way to do this easily? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have access to window functions, you can `JOIN` the `customer_table` to a table of total customers per month & year, and compute the percentage from that:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       c.NumberOfCustomers / t.TotalCustomers * 100 AS PercentageCustomersPerMonth
FROM customer_table c
JOIN (SELECT Month, Year, SUM(NumberOfCustomers) AS TotalCustomers
      FROM customer_table
      GROUP BY Month, Year) t ON c.Month = t.Month AND c.Year = t.Year
```

Output:

```
Gender  Category        Month   Year    NumberOfCustomers   PercentageCustomersPerMonth
female  Feature Phones  1       2019    1000                0.4149
male    Feature Phones  1       2019    10000               4.1494
female  Smart Phones    1       2019    30000               12.4481
male    Smart Phones    1       2019    200000              82.9876
female  Feature Phones  2       2019    20000               9.3023
male    Feature Phones  2       2019    15000               6.9767
female  Smart Phones    2       2019    30000               13.9535
male    Smart Phones    2       2019    150000              69.7674
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/witN7pp1ujLFGSGJjsAVhZ/0)

Answer (score 4):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT gender, category, month, year, 
       SUM(number_of_customers) AS numberOfCustomers,
       (SUM(number_of_customers) /
        SUM(SUM(number_of_customers)) OVER (PARTITION BY year, month)
       ) as month_ratio
FROM customer_table 
WHERE brand_id IN (100) AND
      category in (1,2) AND   
      month in (1, 2) AND
      year in (2019)
GROUP BY month, year, category, gender;
```